# Header not being printed

Tags: awk

I'm using awk with two conditions, that column 25 has a value greater than 333 and less than or equal to 500. The header isn't being captured and sent to the output file, why? What condition do I need to declare as well?

```
awk '$25 > 333 && $25 <= 500' av_bngc6522_Hband_chi1p5_IR_10 > lumbin_500
```

My header starts with a '#'.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean the "header"? is it the label line (the first line), which should be anyway in output?

Comment: Yes, the first line. I thought that's what 'header' was defined as. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this line, just reuse your awk command:

```
awk 'NR==1 || ($25 > 333 && $25 <= 500)' av_bngc6522_Hband_chi1p5_IR_10 > lumbin_500
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: just read and print the first line in the BEGIN section:

```
awk 'BEGIN { getline; print } $25 > 333 && $25 <= 500' av_bngc6522_Hband_chi1p5_IR_10 > lumbin_500
```